# Correct Way to use returned ApiGility Implicit Token

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

My app receives an access token by virtue of an implicit grant. Now I am attempting to use this token to access the content servers RPC service. I am not 100% sure if this is the correct way to do it as I am unable to get it to work.

```
 $code = (string) $this->params()->fromQuery('code', null);

    $client = new HttpClient(
        'http://www.example.com/api/books',
        array(
            'maxredirects' => 0,
            'timeout' => 30
        )
    );

    $client->setMethod('GET');

    $client->setHeaders(
        [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$code
        ]
    );

    try {
        $response = $client->send();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
       throw new \Exception($e);

    }
```

Here is the example in postman which is failing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this question the authorization_code was used and not the access_token and that's why it failed.